# How to generate a view for most viewed posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

I am trying to generate a view of the 8 most viewed posts in the last 24 hours in my rails app. I have implemented a view counter and it is working but I don't know how to locate the 8 most viewed. I would like each post to be shown inside of its own button type module.

here is my pins model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :unique => true # view counter

belongs_to :user
end
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what needs to be added to my pins controller and what to add to my view so that each top viewed pin is displayed in its own separate button.

Comment: what's the name for the column that count the number of visits? if you have that is a very simple solution. And what's the rails version that you are using?

Comment: @DemiMagus the column is impressions_count and I'm using rails 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are updating with every view of the site the column impressions_count in the Pin model.

I will give you an example assuming that you want to show the top 8 most viewed post in your index action of the Pin Controller:

### controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #You can use whether 1.days.ago or 24.hours.ago
    @top_eight_posts = Pin.where(updated_at: 1.days.ago..DateTime.now).order('impressions_count DESC').first(8)
  end

end
```

Then in your index view, or any view that matches the action in the controller, you just need to do an each loop to get the 8 top posts

### views/pins/index.html.erb

```
<% @top_eight_posts.each do |post| %>
  <!-- Assuming Pin Post have a title -->
  <%= post.title %>
  <!-- Assuming Pin Post have a content -->
  <%= post.content %>
<% end %>
```

I hope it helps!!

PD: Updated with the 24 hour filter

Comment: This code works great for displaying the first 8 pins in my database, but it isnt displaying them in order of which pin has the most views. Is there anything I should add to sort by most viewed? I would like this to be so its most viewed in past 24 hours so it should be changing daily. You've helped tremendously already so thank you

Comment: oh i forgot to add the 24 hours filter!

Comment: Almost there! That solved the time issue. Now I am just trying to figure out why it is not ordered by # of page views. I have a counter_cache for each pin that stores # of unique views. This counter works and displays the number of views but the pins are only being ordered by updated_at and the view counts are neglected. Any ideas?

Comment: you said before that the counter was `impressions_count ` and i'm using that, but i'm assuming that when you are updating the `impressions_count ` or `counter_cache` you are also changing the updated at with an update query or something (maybe a `touch` to the model?)

Comment: Okay yes I'm having trouble figuring out where exactly the view count is being stored. I know it is being stored because it is showing on my page and it's working, but when I use counter_cache or impressions_cache I still have no luck. Thank you for your help as your solution is the correct solution the problem is something I am doing!

Comment: I'm glad to know that i was helpful. Have you considered searching in other model? maybe that field is in a related model or something